# Deferred: Name server host name lookup failure (smart host)

Tags: mail, sendmail

am using the sendmail to send an email and configure it as the following : 
/etc/mail/sendmail.mc

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`smtp-server')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/authinfo')dnl
```

/etc/mail/authinfo

```
AuthInfo:smtp-server "U:username@host.com" "P:password" "M:PLAIN"
```

**after that i run the following command :** 
$ m4 sendmail.mc >sendmail.cf 
$ makemap hash authinfo < authinfo 
$ /etc/init.d/sendmail restart

and test it with : 
/usr/sbin/sendmail -v mabdalmahdi@gmail.com < body.txt

but still cant receive any email ?? and i got the following error

```
Deferred: Name server:smtp-server-name: host name lookup failure <br>
```

i tried i can ping to the smtp server , and i run the command dig smpt-server-name 
i cant see any thing wrong ... why i got this message and cant revise an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp-server]')dnl
```

It should turn off lookups for MX records. If it does not help try Ipv4 address inside square brackets.

Comment: you are right ... and the ISP was block the smtp port :) ...